# Find & Round the time to nearest half an hour from a single file

Tags: r

I have yearly time data for one year in a single file with 30 min interval such as

```
"01-01-2013 00:00" "01-01-2013 00:30" "01-01-2013 01:00" "01-01-2013 01:30" "01-01-2013 02:00" "01-01-2013 02:30".....
```

But in the entire data, some of them contains

```
"08-28-2013 14:53", "08-28-2013 15:37"
```

I need to find those from the entire record and to replace(round off) into 30 mins time interval like

```
"08-28-2013 15:00", "08-28-2013 15:30"
```

Help me in this..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
datetimes <- c("08-28-2013 14:53", "08-28-2013 15:37")
datetimes <- strptime(datetimes, "%m-%d-%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT")
datetimes$min <- round(datetimes$min / 30) * 30
#1] "2013-08-28 15:00:00 GMT" "2013-08-28 15:30:00 GMT"
```

Comment: Nice one, I was thinking to use `foverlaps`, but this one is certainly simpler

Comment: @DavidArenburg The main lesson: If you have to round datetimes, POSIXlt is useful. Otherwise, avoid it and use POSIXct.